# Algorithm to check if a polygon is a projection of a polyhedron

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to develop an algorithm that performs the following :

Given a 2D polygon and a 3D polyhedron, determine if the 2D polygon is a projection of the 3D polyhedron (a perspective projection to be precise) without knowing which transformation matrix we may have possibly used for the projection.

**input**

- {2D Polygon}
- {3D Polyhedron}

**output**

- {bool} whether or not it's a perspective projection

I am not asking for code, but I would simply like to know if this is feasible in polynomial time.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is 3D-polygon just planar polygon with 3D-coordinates?

Comment: I apologize, I should have been more explicit. By 3D polygon I mean a non-planar polygon, and by 2D polygon I mean a planar polygon

Comment: No need to apologize! 3D means 3 axes; 3 axes mean non-planar unless one goes out of their way and say that all the points that belong to a certain axis have the same value, which takes us down to 2D space, the planar space for doing geometry.

Comment: I think it might depend on the context. How is the 2D polygon given/obtained ? Are overlapping 2D vertexes combined to 1 vertex ? Do you know which 2D vertexes are connected or do you only see the lines ?

Comment: @mohsenmadi, planar does not mean parallel to some axis. For example, any triangle in 3D is planar (that is, all vertices belong to *some* plane). So OP says that his 3D-polygon might be "bent". Or probably he means not *polygon*, but *polyhedron*?..

Comment: Let me give an example : the 3D shape is lets say a 3D model, and the 2D shape is its "silhouette" seen from a certain angle. Guess I meant a polyhedron

Comment: Sure. any three point define a plane, a plane in an infinite world of planes. Such a plane can be defined by a couple of axes - a vector and a normal to it - two axes in an infinite set of axes. 3D objects cannot be contained in 2D planes unless the constraint I gave in the above comment apply.

Answer (score 4):

A 3D to 2D perspective projection has 7 degrees of freedom (6 for the relative motion of the scene with respect to the camera, 1 for the focal length).

Select four vertices in the 2D projection and consider all possible correspondences with polyhedron vertices (there is a polynomial number of such associations). Then form a system of 7 equations in the 7 unknown parameters (unfortunately a nonlinear one; maybe the eighth equation can be useful to select among multiple solutions).

Knowing the parameters, you can check a solution by re-projecting the polyhedron and comparing to the polygon (with further search for correspondences with vertices and edges).

All of this will take polynomial time (quartic if I am right), if one admits that the solver takes bounded time (hence bounded precision).

---

If the **focal length is known**, then a better approach is possible. Indeed, with only 6 unknowns, you can find the projection parameters from the projection of just three points. This problem is known to have an **analytical** solution (actually up to 4 of them), as described at length in "New Algorithms for the Perspective-Three-Point Problem, GAO Xiaoshan & CHEN Hangfei, Vol.16 No.3 J. Comput. Sci. & Technol."

This should lead to an O(N³) exact procedure.

---

More generally speaking, you form putative correspondences between N pairs of points, solve the corresponding Perspective-N-point problem, and check the hypothesis by reprojecting the polyhedron and comparing to the known projection to validate the hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea for an algorithm:

Take a triangle of the projection made of three points next to each other not on the same line. Iterate through all corresponding triangles of the original. For all possible projections that solve the pair of triangles, check if the rest matches.

I must admit I am not sure right now if there could be infinite solutions for triangles (which would be hard to iterate)? If so, start with four points.

Comment: all possible projections? I think there are infinitely many, unless we 'discretized' the space. But I doubt it would execute in a reasonable time

Comment: For all possible projections for the given pair of sets of points.

Comment: This could be a perfect solution for the case of an orthographic projection.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is possible but you have to do a fair amount of reverse engineering. A 2D sketch that represents a 3D object is known as an [Orthographic Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection). The link shows you the transformation matrices you need apply to transform the 3D point onto its 2D projection. Now, how do you go the opposite way? Inverse matrices with a mix of some inverse transformations (translation, scaling, rotation...)? I think this is a good lead to follow.